# Root ViewController View is not taking TabBar and NavBar into account

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiviewcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I have a viewcontroller that is embedded in both a navigation and tabbar viewcontroller.  I had assumed that the self.view would geometrically be the bounds starting at the bottom of the navbar and the top of the tab bar.  This is what I have read online.  That by `viewWillAppear` the view is resized to subtract the tab and nav bar from the height, essentially.  However, this is not happening for me.  When I log out the frame of my view it is the same... `{{0, 0}, {375, 667}}`.  In `viewDidLoad`, `viewDidLayoutSubview`, `willAppear`, DidAppear it is that same frame.  Therefore, if I put an imageView as a subview of self.view with a frame `(0,0,screenWidth, 200)`.  That imageView appears occluded by the nav bar.  To my reading, this isn't the standard behavior.

Answer (score 0):

If you want that your UIViewController starts below the navigation bar put this on viewDidLoad:

```
self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;
```

Comment: I still cannot change my view's frame.  That seems to result in a different frame, one with a lesser height.  but if i create a new view and assign it to self.view in viewWillAppear it disregards that and logs out the same frame.

Comment: The code I posted does not change the frame at all. It only prevents UIViewController from extending below the navigation bar. To help you debug the problem put some borders around UIViews

Comment: it does change the view.  the view's height is actually now the screen height minue the status+tab+nav bars.  its just that i can't manually change the frame myself in any of the view* methods.